# Merge the [gestures] into [gesture]?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-process

[gesture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gesture) has about 5 times the number of questions that [gestures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gestures) has. The tag descriptions don't suggest any real distinction between the two. Here are the excerpts:

## gesture

> A gesture is a specific pattern of touch, cursor, or physical movement that may be recognized by an application to perform a specific task.

## gestures

> The tag refers to a method of interaction with graphical user interface. Instead of simply choosing, user may draw a shape (so called gesture) over an item, which is recognized by the software and triggers specific reaction. Gestures are very popular, but not limited to touchscreen applications.